# Determining roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial function of degree $n \geq 2$.
>   Determine the largest possible number of roots of the equation $f′(x)=0$.

I don't get how to do this as the question doesn't say what $f(x)$ is. Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that, by the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), for a polynomial of degree $n$ the largest number of distinct real roots is $n$.

Moreover the degree of $f'(x)$ is $n-1$.

Comment: if the degree of f '(x) is n-1 would the largest possible roots just be 1?

Comment: @lhf Yes you are right! I fix that. Thanks

Comment: @Maths The maximu number of roots is equal to the degree of $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* What is the degree of $f'$ ?

Comment: would the degree be $n \geq 1$?

Comment: @Maths, no, the degree of $f'$ is $n-1$.